# Is there a downside to validating data through a static method of the Model in an MVP setting?

Tags: validation, mvp

I was recently [reading about MVP](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/342849-introducing-mvp-model-view-presenter-pattern-winforms/), and at the end of the post the author starts to talk about Validation of Data. He mentions

> I favour a single `isValid()` routine in the view.
>
> ...
>
> An alternative approach, which is more in-line with the pattern, is to include this method in the interface and for the presenter to call this method (`view.isValid()`) before attempting to make changes to the model.

I don't think the validation should be handled in the View because it exposes more about the Model than the View should know, especially since we're trying to keep the View and the Model as separate as possible. Plus that method becomes redundant when you have multiple views referencing the same Model (e.g. a quick summary view vs. a more detailed view).

The Presenter has the most opportunity to validate the data, seeing as it is the bridge between the Model and View. I do like the "alternative approach", but I still don't like how it's using `view.isValid`. Plus I'm still not entirely sure if one presenter controls one view, or multiple view (a question for another time).

But one idea that did occur to me is to use a static `isValid()` method from the Model. You would call it in the Presenter, and the Presenter would pass all the relevant information from the View to the method. The method returns some form of valid or not-valid, maybe even specific enough to say which pieces of information aren't valid. To me this keeps all information relevant to the Model, within the Model, and accessible to Presenter, while keeping the View blissfully unaware of the Model.

Are there any shortcomings to this idea that other Validation practices solve, or is there any glaring downside to this method of Validation?